# Is $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \arctan(x_n) = \arctan( \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be any sequence of real numbers. In a proof I'm reading, it is used that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \arctan(x_n) = \arctan( \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n)$$

where $\arctan: [-\infty, + \infty] \to [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ is the inverse  of $\tan$ extended with $\arctan(\pm\infty) := \pm \pi/2$;

It seems odd to me that you can interchange the $\arctan$ and $\liminf$. I can find counterexamples for continuous functions that this does not hold in general. Is there any reason why this relation does hold for $\arctan$? Or is my book wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true for any increasing continuous function (on the extended real line with finite limits at $\pm \infty)$.  $\arctan $ has these properties.

Comment: I believe that hard to believe. What if $\liminf x_n = + \infty$ and $f$ is continuous and increasing but only defined on $\mathbb{R}$? How you make sense of $f( \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_ n)$? And can you please provide a proof of this fact then?

Comment: @user661541 Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: And with continuous you mean continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user661541 A function $f:[-\infty, \infty] \to \mathbb R$ is called continuous if it is continuous on $\mathbb R$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=f(\infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=f(-\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I  understand the statement, do you know a reference for a proof?

Comment: @user661541 Just apply the definition of $\lim \inf$ and note that $\inf_{k \geq n} f(x_k)=f( \inf_{k \geq n} f(x_k))$ for  each $n$ (since $f$ is increasing) . Then take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to work out the details.